# how to Store large number in a cell with PHPExcel?

Tags: php, html

I am using Phpexcel class to convert a file as xlsx file. In this file have a large value like 1262166000008972 but after converting xlsx file it shows
1262166000009000.
I try with these options
Ex:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit('G6:G1000', '', PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

I try with these binding value

```
class PHPExcel_Cell_MyColumnValueBinder extends 
  PHPExcel_Cell_DefaultValueBinder implements PHPExcel_Cell_IValueBinder
  {
protected $stringColumns = [];

public function __construct(array $stringColumnList = []) {
    // Accept a list of columns that will always be set as strings
    $this->stringColumns = $stringColumnList;
}

public function bindValue(PHPExcel_Cell $cell, $value = null)
{
    // If the cell is one of our columns to set as a string...
    if (in_array($cell->getColumn(), $this->stringColumns)) {
        // ... then we cast it to a string and explicitly set it as a string
        $cell->setValueExplicit((string) $value, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
        return true;
    }
    // Otherwise, use the default behaviour
    return parent::bindValue($cell, $value);
}
```

}

```
 PHPExcel_Cell::setValueBinder(new PHPExcel_Cell_MyColumnValueBinder(['G']));
```

It works in localhost,but in server not working

Comment: This doesn't look like a PHPExcel issue but an Excel issue instead... Too large numbers are automatically converted by Excel to scientific notation. A workaround would be to first define an explicit number formatting for the cell which doesn't automatically convert the number to scientific notation and then place the number

Comment: Also you can try to add additional ' in the begining.  " '680540101947000270348604"

Comment: any suggestion . how to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

change getcell value into getcellexplicit. it converts char. now its working fine.